# Android KeyStore problem, another device same app

Tags: java, android, keystore

What I want is Using android keystore so that I want to hide the crypto key.

This is the code.

```
    String alias = "testalias";
    KeyStoreManager.init(getApplicationContext());
    String plain = "helloWorld";
    String enc = KeyStoreManager.encryptData(plain, alias);
    Log.d(TAG, "enc = " + enc);
```

I saved `enc` string to a variable named `encText` and run again.

```
String alias = "testalias";
KeyStoreManager.init(getApplicationContext());
String plain = "helloWorld";
String enc = KeyStoreManager.encryptData(plain, alias);
Log.d(TAG, "enc = " + enc);
String encText = "AcasR3G2Oai+Misqcsacw0Fmnj96vrEqV0Cdmc3ycT2FoEvmVZFAk6ZyG+Srww26R+slDl/32a/D\n" +
            "uaQQQxBqbW0uO5pwUL5HIFb3WBiPm1dh5JsHfQ==";
String dec = KeyStoreManager.decryptData(encText, alias);
// dec : helloWorld
```

It was decoded properly.

However, the problem occurs on other devices. Deciphering `encText` on another device will cause a `PaddingException`.

**Is it impossible?**

1. device'A' -> encrypt text using KeyStore.
2. device'B' -> decrypt that text using KeyStore. **--> exception**
   (using same .jks, same app, same code)

=== About Keystoremanager ===

Keystoremanager class base on **java.security.KeyStore**
using *.jks files

```
public String encryptString(String alias, String plainText) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException, KeyStoreException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    String encryptedText = "";
    createKeys(context, alias);
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
    RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();

    Cipher inCipher = getCipher();
    inCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, inCipher);
    cipherOutputStream.write(plainText.getBytes(CHARSET));
    cipherOutputStream.close();

    byte[] vals = outputStream.toByteArray();
    encryptedText = (Base64.encodeToString(vals, Base64.DEFAULT));

    return encryptedText;
}
```

Comment: Hello Bryan! Keystore is a vault of created keys for your application. I am not quite sure I do follow you, but Keystore is not used for encrypting/decrpyting anything.

Comment: You appear to be using some third party library that provides some `KeyStoreManager` class. But you haven't mentioned which library it is, or how the `KeyStoreManager` class works.

Comment: The AndroidKeyStore is device specific, each device will generate a different key. Therefore AES encryption and decryption only works on the same device.

Comment: Hi Bryan. If you need two devices to exchange encrypted data, you should encrypt with the public key of the device that's going to decrypt it. If Device A is going to send encrypted data to Device B,  A  must first obtain the public key of B and encrypt the data with it. When B receives the data, B can decrypt the data with its own private key.

Comment: thanks for replies.
It's not about transfer between devices. What I want to do is hide encryption key string into my android source code.
I'm worried that if others look at the encryption key with a tool such as jadx, they can decrypt the encrypted file.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, a walk-around. 
A password scenario, that the AES Key for encrypting the password is stored in the Keystore.

There is an overhead in this solution and here it is.

Since the Keystore is device specific, when the user tries to log in on a new device, he is verified via Email/SMS. If the user is verified, you can tell the user to enter a new password (or the same text), and on the new device another Keystore alias is created.

So in summary, your app is device-specific, if the user is to use it on another device, he would have to be verified first, then the user can use the same text/another one.